# Making a deck of cards in Racket

Tags: racket

I am trying to use Racket to make a full deck of playing cards for a BlackJack game. However, I have two problems:

1. When I use the following code

   ```
   ;This function creates a list of all the card faces.
   (define faces '(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A))
   ;This function creates a list of all card suits.
   (define suits '(Clubs Diamonds Hearts Spades))

   ;make-deck: Creates a new (unshuffled) 52 card deck
   ;     Returns: The deck (a list of cards)
   ;     Parameters: none

   (define make-deck
     (letrec ([pair-items (lambda (x y)
                            (cond
                              [(null? x) '()]
                              [(null? y) '()]
                              [(displayln (cons (car x) (cons (car y) (pair-items x (cdr y)))))]
                              ))])                 
       (pair-items faces suits))
     )
   ```

   I get

   ```
   (2 Spades)
   (2 Hearts . #<void>)
   (2 Diamonds . #<void>)
   (2 Clubs . #<void>)
   ```

   And I do not know what the issue is.
2. I have no idea how to reset the `iterator` to pair the next element in the `faces` function with the whole of the `suits` function. Do I use `let`?

Comment: Using `displayln` as a test expression in `cond` makes no sense.

Comment: Why does it not make sense?

Comment: It doesn't *test* anything, it just *does* something. And always returns a true value (`(void)`), and without a body... well, [read the documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29) for what happens in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial way is to use [`cartesian-product`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._cartesian-product%29%29) to generate the list of cards (You can also use [`for*/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2A%2Flist%29%29) to iterate over your `faces` and `suits` lists to get the same effect). Both demonstrated below:

```lisp
#lang racket/base

(require racket/list)

;This function creates a list of all the card faces.
(define faces '(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A))
;This function creates a list of all card suits.
(define suits '(Clubs Diamonds Hearts Spades))

; These two variables should be equal?
(define deck-1 (cartesian-product faces suits))
(define deck-2 (for*/list ([face (in-list faces)]
                           [suit (in-list suits)])
                 (list face suit)))
```

---

A big issue with your code is using `(cond ... [(displayln ...)])`. `displayln` always returns a [void value](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/void_undefined.html), which, since it's not `#f`, is always going to count as true in a `cond`. And without a *test-body* part of that *cond-clause*, what the true *test-expr* returns is what the `cond` evaluates to, so that's what you're getting added to the lists your function is printing (But **not** returning). You should probably start by splitting the *display* of data apart from the *creation* of it.